# 403 access forbidden error on localhost when getting data from api

Tags: javascript, php, xampp

I'm using an api to get the weather data all things seem to work fine but when I try to display the image in that api data using its path it gives an error of 403 forbidden access
using this api to retrieve data
http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=5bff99016340441d8cc184738221209&q=islamabad&aqi=no
it returns an icon at this address://cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/day/176.png
But the icon can't be displayed and shows 403 error in console

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved. Is this a PHP question, a Javascript question, or a XAMPP question?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.